# Multiple conditional clause filter in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to filter a table, but some request values can be null. Is there a way to make it more simple, or do I need to create multiple IF statements?

```php
$archives = Archive::when($vehicle, function ($query) use ($vehicle) {
    return $query->where('vehicle_id', $vehicle);
})->when($month, function ($query) use ($month) {
    return $query->whereMonth('startduration', $month)
        ->orWhereMonth('endduration', $month);
})->when($year, function ($query) use ($year) {
    return $query->whereYear('startduration', $year)
        ->orWhereYear('endduration', $year);
})->when($status, function ($query) use ($status) {
    return $query->where('archivedtype', $status);
})->orderBy('endduration', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: It would be best to pass valid data to the query functions.  Use multiple If's checking if it's null or not.  The old saying, "Garbage in is Garbage out".  From that, you can error properly if needed or modify the query to only do what it should.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Thanks

```
$archives = Archive::where( function($query) use($request){
                return $request->vehicle ? $query->where('vehicle_id',$request->vehicle) : '';
            })
            ->where(function($query) use($request){
                return $request->month ? $query->whereMonth('startduration',$request->month)->orWhereMonth('endduration',$request->month) : '';
            })
            ->where(function($query) use($request){
                return $request->year ? $query->whereYear('startduration',$request->year)->orWhereYear('endduration',$request->year) : '';
            })
            ->where( function($query) use($request){
                return $request->status ? $query->where('archivedtype',$request->status) : '';
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$archives = Archive::query()
    ->when($request->month, function ($query, $m) {
        $query->where(fn ($q) => $q->whereMonth('startduration', $m)->orWhereMonth('endduration', $m));
    })
    ->when($request->year, function ($query, $y) {
        $query->where(fn ($q) => $q->whereYear('startduration', $y)->orWhereYear('endduration', $y))
    })
    ->when($request->vehicle, fn ($q, $v) => $q->where('vehicle_id', $v))
    ->when($request->status, fn ($q, $s) => $q->where('archivedtype', $s))
    ->orderBy('endduration', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.